# Look Up Post Without Using Primary Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, database-design, primary-key

To fetch a certain post in my controller you can type something like this in the URL

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/1
http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/2
http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/3
```

I am being asked to make it so that it can't be fetched this way but with a random string. For example something more like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/wr4t-d2e2-1ee3
http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/prst-3r4t-1r1r
http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/asdo-2e12-sxas
```

**Question**
In order to do this should I create another column in the post table called 'token' or 'random' and use that column via find_by  to fetch the post? i.e. Post.find_by_token('wr4t-d2e2-1ee3')

Any opinions on what is the right way to deal with this.
I have been reading up on examples where apps will use **'surrogate key'**, **'guid'**, **'natural key'**, **token**, **random**

I'm just a little overwhelmed on what the best practice is.

Comment: I don't think there's a clear answer as to best practice for what to use. Personally I would look for something relevant to what you're serving: UPC, Isbn, underscored blog post titles, etc. the important thin will be indexing that column. Others do what works.

Comment: Lemme guess, you have a multi tenant system and don't want users to see other tenants post by id

Comment: Yeah, client doesn't want the posts to be so accessible and predictable. (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) in a logical order.

Comment: If it's multi-tenant, just changing the URL shouldn't give any random person access to other tenant's data. (If it's multi-tenant, tag it that way. Multi-tenant databases can be tricky.)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is this:

```
   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
     # Permalinks
     #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     def to_param
        "#{post.token}"
     end
   end
```

Url's will generate as

```
post_url(@post)
#http://0.0.0.0:3000/post/wr4t-d2e2-1ee3
```

Then you can do as per normal

```
Post.find(params[:id])
```

You can generate your token by just using before_validation callback.

OR

You can go a gem and use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) which will handle this for you, as well as track history of slugs that are generated.  Tho, sounds like it it's probably overkill for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the friendly_id gem. https://github.com/norman/friendly_id.

RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

You will need a `token` column which, if you are using Devise, can generate with `Devise.friendly_token` method.

Comment: I think this gem will help. Thanks.